# No such module 'MaterialComponents.MaterialCards_ColorThemer'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, material-components-ios

I am new in swift development 
Im trying to implement Material Card in my App. I've Installed `'MaterialComponents' using Cocoapods.`
I can 
`import MaterialComponents`     in my ViewController
but when I go and import

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialCard_ColorThemer
```

It Gives me an error  :

```
No such module 'MaterialComponents.MaterialCards_ColorThemer'
```

Am I missing something here ?

PodFile:

```
target 'Melange' do

  use_frameworks!
  pod 'MaterialComponents'


  # Pods for Melange

  target 'MelangeTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MelangeUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: clean your project and run the app. Sometime it display errors but when you run your application and then error has disappeared.

Comment: @VisalSambo I tried that, didn't work

Comment: Just `import MaterialComponets` in your specific class then you can access all its components... This is what i have done.... and it works for me...

Comment: @VisalSambo I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: just import MaterialComponents.MaterialButtons, and pod 'MaterialComponents'

Comment: Same thing happens to me . Have you found any solution?

Comment: @ajithKumark nope :(

Comment: did you tried  any other framework other than material components?

Comment: Thats happen when you have  multiple target and library is written with Objective-c

Answer (score -1):

Try to set specific version of pod. In my case it's works with:

`pod 'MaterialComponents', '~> 94.2'`